# Are there any statistical measures to determine how "clustered" a dataset is?

Tags: clustering, standard-deviation, measure-theory

I have two datasets that I'm trying to compare.  In one dataset, the points appear to be pretty uniformly distributed.

[image]

In the second dataset, they appear to somewhat more clustered - i.e. there appears to be some cluster centers where nearly all values are the same (although other points in the set are not at all clustered).

[image]

Are there any measures I could use to describe the tendency of the set towards clustering or overlap or something like that (without actually using any clustering methods)?  The mean, standard deviation, and coefficient of variation are very similar between the two sets.

I should add that I'd like some kind of measure because although one set does appear more uniform than the other, since the first set is about 4 times the size of the second set, it is hard to confirm that it truly is more uniform...